# Count occurence in linklist using recursive in java

Tags: java

I insert some elements in Node in java,displaying element also working fine.But when i search any element occurrence using recursive its always return value zero .Sorry wrong for my english.I am new in data structure implementation in java . Thanks

```
public class pal{
    private static Node head;
    private static class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node next;

        Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void addToTheLast(Node node) {

        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            Node temp = head;
            while (temp.next != null)
                temp = temp.next;

            temp.next = node;
        }
    }


    public static void printList() {
        Node temp = head;

        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.format("%d ", temp.value);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int no ;
        Node head = null ;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number of Element ");
        no = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0 ;i< no; i ++){

        System.out.print("Enter Element ");
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            if(head == null){
               head = new Node(a);
                addToTheLast(head);
            }else{
                addToTheLast(new Node(a));
            }
        }
        printList();
                System.out.print("Enter search key");
                int key = sc.nextInt();
                int yo = count(head,key);
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(yo));
    }

        public int count (Node head,int key){
              int cnt = 0;
              if(head == null){
                 return cnt;
              }else{
                  if(temp.value == key)
                      cnt++;
                  count(temp.next,key)
              }
              return cnt;
        }
}
```

Always retun value 0 if element is present in linklist

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile as you are referring to a variable `temp` within count method, but it does not exist.

You have to replace `temp` with `head`.

Also, you are losing the `cnt` value in your recursive call. You are incrementing `cnt` which is a local variable.

I have modified the code to pass along the value of count as a parameter.

```
public static int count(Node head, int key, int count){
    if(head == null){
        return count;
    } else {
        if(head.value == key) {
            return count(head.next, key, count + 1);
        } else {
           return count(head.next, key, count);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want the callers of count to pass 0 to the last parameter (as `count(head, key, 0)`), make it a private method and make the public *search* method call this (I prefer this method as it is cleaner)

```
public static int count(Node head, int key) { //main method calls this
   return call(head, key, 0); //calls the above method
}
```

Comment: Make sure the element you are searching is indeed in the list